# Efficient way to check whether a page changed (while storing as little info as possible)?

Tags: python, hash, web-scraping

I have some webpages where I'm collecting data over time.  I don't care about the content itself, just whether the page has changed.

Currently, I use Python's requests.get to fetch a page, hash the page (md5), and store that hash value to compare in the future.

Is there a computationally cheaper or smaller-storage strategy for this?  Things work now; I just wanted to check if there's a better/cheaper way. :)

Comment: simply faster hash? something like https://code.google.com/p/pyxxhash/ ?

Comment: Are you having space problems?

Comment: Neither -- this was just a solution I came up with on the fly; I wanted to know if there was a more "proper" way of doing it.  As a non-CS major who codes out of necessity, I try to make up for my lack of education with some discipline.

Comment: a hash would be the way to go here. you could also use crc32 if you're just worried about changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hash would be the most trustable source of change detection. I would use CRC32. It's only 32 bits as opposed to 128bits for md5. Also, even in browser Javascript it can be very fast. I have personal experience in improving the speed for a JS implementation of CRC32 for very large datasets.

Comment: Thanks -- appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the date of the last version you got and use the If-Modified-Since header in your request. However, some resources ignore that header. (In general it's difficult to handle it for dynamically-generated content.) In that case you'll have to fall back to less efficient method.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that; and agreed -- for dynamically generated content the timestamp is unreliable though.